Training custom unet model
I'm working on segmentation project. when I tried both custom unet or pretrained full convolution network from pytorch I got theses strange results whatever what are the hyperparameters I use but when I used deeplab pretrained model I got quite reasonable results. Does anyone have an explanation? Thanks


this is the custom model
    import torch
    from torch import nn

    def create_conv_block(in_channels, out_channels):
        conv_block = nn.Sequential(
            nn.Conv2d(in_channels, out_channels, 3, 1, 1, bias=False),
            nn.BatchNorm2d(out_channels),
            nn.ReLU(inplace=True),
            nn.Conv2d(out_channels, out_channels, 3, 1, 1, bias=False),
            nn.BatchNorm2d(out_channels),
            nn.ReLU(inplace=True))
        return conv_block

    class Encoder(nn.Module):
        def __init__(self, channels) -> None:
            super().__init__()
            blocks = []
            for i in range(len(channels)-1):
                conv_block = create_conv_block(channels[i], channels[i+1])
                blocks.append(conv_block)

            self.model = nn.ModuleList(blocks)
            self.maxpool = nn.MaxPool2d(kernel_size=2, stride=2)

        def forward(self, x):
            features = []
            for module in self.model:
                x = module(x)
                features.append(x)
                x = self.maxpool(x)
            return features

    class Decoder(nn.Module):
        def __init__(self, channels) -> None:
            super().__init__()
            blocks = []
            for i in range(len(channels)-2):
                up_sampling_layer = nn.Sequential(nn.ConvTranspose2d(
            in_channels=channels[i], out_channels=channels[i+1], kernel_size=2, stride=2))
                blocks.append(up_sampling_layer)

                conv_block = create_conv_block(channels[i+1]*2, channels[i+1])
                blocks.append(conv_block)

            blocks.append(nn.Sequential(nn.Conv2d(in_channels=channels[-2], out_channels=21, kernel_size=1)))

            self.model = nn.ModuleList(blocks)

        def forward(self, x, encoder_featuers):
            for i, module in enumerate(self.model):
                if i % 2:
                    x = torch.cat([encoder_featuers.pop(), x], dim=1)
                x = module(x)
            return x

    class UNet(nn.Module):
        def __init__(self, channels):
            super().__init__()
            self.encoder = Encoder(channels)
            self.decoder = Decoder(channels[::-1])

        def forward(self, x):
            encoder_features = self.encoder(x)
            x = self.decoder(encoder_features[-1], encoder_features[:-1])

    return x

And this is the training function
    def train(loader, model, loss_fn, optimizer):
        model.train()
        epoch_loss = 0
        for images, masks in loader:
            images = images.to("cuda")
            masks = masks.type(torch.LongTensor).to("cuda")

            optimizer.zero_grad()
            outputs = model(images)["out"]
            loss = loss_fn(outputs, masks)
            epoch_loss += loss.item()

            loss.backward()
            optimizer.step()

        return epoch_loss / len(loader)

And this is the validation function
    def validate(loader, model, loss_fn):
        model.eval()
        epoch_loss = 0
        dice_score = 0
        with torch.no_grad():
            for images, masks in loader:
                images = images.to("cuda")
                masks = masks.type(torch.LongTensor).to("cuda")

                outputs = model(images)["out"]
                loss = loss_fn(outputs, masks)
                epoch_loss += loss.item()
                outputs = torch.argmax(outputs, dim=1)

                dice_score += calc_dice_score(outputs, masks)

            return epoch_loss / len(loader), dice_score / len(loader)

And this dice score function
    def calc_dice_score(preds, targets):
        intersection = ((preds == targets) & (targets != 0)).sum()
        union = (preds > 0).sum() + (targets > 0).sum()

        dice_score = 2.0 * intersection / union
        return dice_score.item()


What's the loss function you're using here?
